# C++ how to access base class static members in derived class?

Tags: c++, static-members

I am new to c++ static varibles. I don't know how to access the static member of base class from the derived class member function.

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class base // base class
{
protected:
    static int value;
};

int base::value = 0; // static variable initalization

class derived : public base
{
public:
    get_variable();
};
```

I know that static variable is a class variable. We can only access it by using class name and it is not binded to object (correct me if I'm wrong). My question is how can I access the static variable in the member functions of the derived class `get_varible` access the static variable.?

Comment: So long as the variable is private you can't access it in the derived class.

Answer (score 2):

You should change `private` to  `protected` in base class.
Your `private static` variable can be only accessed within `base` class.

Answer (score 1):

Just use it as it's a member of the derived class.

```
int derived::get_variable()
{
   return value; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the variable from the derived class like this:

```
int derived::get_variable()
{
     return base::value;
}
```

You need to use the name of the base class because the variable is static and you're allowed to access it because it is protected.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913451/why-calling-a-protected-static-method-in-derived-classes-is-allowed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393325/why-is-protected-constructor-raising-an-error-this-this-code), the extra checks that don't allow access to protected members of a class from a derived class in certain circumstances don't apply to static members.